# Custom view in UIWebView swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiwebview

I need add custom view in `UIWebView`. `UIWebView` has `open var scrollView: UIScrollView` with one subview `UIWebBrowserView`. The point is I try add `UIView` to `UIScrollView` at position [0] but `UIWebBrowserView` overlaps my view. So, How can I add myView above `UIWebBrowserView`

```
func insertSubview(_ view: UIView, aboveSubview siblingSubview: UIView)
```

Does not work too. In that case view overlap `UIWebBrowserView`

Comment: Did you consider the option to add it to the keyWindow or is it impossible for you?

Comment: @MartinM I need to make it scrollable. btw its not recommended add views to the keyWindow

Comment: Are you using `UIWebView`? or `WKWebView`? If the former, you should be using  `WKWebView` --- quick test shows no problem adding a view as a subview of the web view's `scrollView`.

Comment: @DonMag thanks, I will check it